# Finding and testing primality

Tags: c#, primes

I have written a class who is responsible for both enumerating primes and testing the primality of a number.

Here is the code :

```
public static class Primes
{
    private static ulong g_MaxTested;
    private static ulong g_MaxFound;

    private static readonly HashSet<ulong> g_KnownPrimes;

    static Primes()
    {
        // All primes below 1000 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes)
        g_KnownPrimes = new HashSet<ulong>() {
            2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 
            79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 
            167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 
            257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 
            353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 
            449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 
            563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 
            653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 
            761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 
            877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 
            991, 997
        };

        g_MaxTested = 997;
        g_MaxFound = 997;

    }

    private static void EnsureExploredUpTo(ulong upperBound)
    {
        if (upperBound <= g_MaxTested) return;

        for (g_MaxTested += 2; g_MaxTested <= upperBound; g_MaxTested += 2)
        {
            if (TestPrimality(g_MaxTested))
            {
                g_KnownPrimes.Add(g_MaxTested);
                g_MaxFound = g_MaxTested;
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool TestPrimality(ulong value)
    {
        if (value == 1) return false;
        var sqrt = (ulong)Math.Sqrt(value);
        return !g_KnownPrimes
            .TakeWhile(x => x <= sqrt)
            .Any(x => value % x == 0);
    }

    public static bool IsPrime(ulong value)
    {
        if (value == 1) return false;
        EnsureExploredUpTo(value);
        return g_KnownPrimes.Contains(value);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ulong> GetPrimes(ulong upperBound = ulong.MaxValue)
    {
        // First return all known primes : 
        foreach (var prime in g_KnownPrimes)
        {
            if (prime > upperBound) yield break;
            yield return prime;
        }
        // then, if required, continue exploring :
        for (g_MaxTested += 2; g_MaxTested <= upperBound; g_MaxTested += 2)
        {
            if (TestPrimality(g_MaxTested))
            {
                g_KnownPrimes.Add(g_MaxTested);
                g_MaxFound = g_MaxTested;
                yield return g_MaxTested; // yield the result for immediate use
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Key concepts :

- The idea of the class is to maintain a "cursor" of explored number, and a list of known primes.
- The known primes (`g_KnownPrimes`) allows me to test a number like using a sieve (as a non prime number is always a multiple of another prime (`TestPrimality` method).
- When I want to test a number outside the explored number range, I explorer from the last tested to the number to test (`EnsureExploreredUpTo` method)
- When I want to enumerate all primes, I start to yield known primes, then use the same logic than `EnsureExplorerdUpTo`, but with yielding each prime found.

I have validated my code using these tests :

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetPrimesTest()
    {
        var primes = Primes.GetPrimes();
        var enumerator = primes.GetEnumerator();

        Assert.IsTrue(enumerator.MoveNext());
        Assert.AreEqual(enumerator.Current, 2UL);
        Assert.IsTrue(enumerator.MoveNext());
        Assert.AreEqual(enumerator.Current, 3UL);

        do
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(enumerator.MoveNext());

        } while (enumerator.Current < 997); // Last prime below 1000

        Assert.IsTrue(enumerator.MoveNext());
        Assert.AreEqual(enumerator.Current, 1009UL);
        Assert.IsTrue(enumerator.MoveNext());
        Assert.AreEqual(enumerator.Current, 1013UL);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void _1IsNotPrimeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(Primes.IsPrime(1));
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void _2IsPrimeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Primes.IsPrime(2));
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void _3IsPrimeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Primes.IsPrime(3));
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void _42IsNotPrimeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(Primes.IsPrime(42));
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void _2001IsNotPrimeTest()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(Primes.IsPrime(2001));
    }
```

So my question are :

- Is this approach valid ? I've googled a bit but without finding better algorithms.
- I use the `HashSet<ulong>` class, as it seems to be the more efficient list for my case. Am I right ?
- I know this class is not thread safe at all. Can I "simply" make it thread-safe ? (maybe this should be a dedicated question on [so].

Comment: Why not port this clever python code to your language? http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/excerpt/pythonckbk_chap1/index1.html?page=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid sieve but the HashSet MAY not be as fast as an Array or ArrayList. These will preserve the order of the elements, so you could implement a quick membership check with a binary search. They would likely be faster to iterate over in general -- they should especially speed up iteration for testing the primality of a sequence of odd numbers. In 33% of the cases, the testing would not get past `x % 3`.  Doing these tests in HashSet order wastes lots of time checking against higher primes in the HashSet that rarely change the outcome. Listing primes in a HashSet order that may change as the set of primes grows seems slightly less useful than listing in increasing order.

BTW, testing odd numbers for `x % 2` is a waste of time, especially if that's going to be the first test -- you might want to consider pulling 2 out of your primes list and handling it separately only when you have to.

But you should definitely *benchmark* either of these suggestions on a mix of input sequences with typical numbers of input values, maximum input values, and tendencies to raise the high water value early vs. late in the sequence.

One last note: `g_MaxFound` doesn't cost much and is nice for diagnostic purposes, but it's not actually used in the implementation. I usually mark non-critical variables like this with special names or at least comments to avoid confusion with the operational values.

Comment: SortedSet has ln(n) for .Contains so would avoid implementing your own binary search. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

Comment: @Joey Good point. It'd be interesting to benchmark ArrayList w/ a homegrown binary search vs. SortedSet at different scales for this special case of always inserting a new max element and never removing elements.

Answer (score 1):

How large are the numbers that you will be testing for primality? If you have an upper bound then it might be better to use a sieve of Eratosthenes to find all the primes up to `sqrt(upperBound)`. That way you don't need to keep checking whether you need to extend your explored range.

In answer to your questions:

1) Your approach seems valid. However, it might pay off to extend your explored range by more than 2 at a time using a sieve approach, e.g. start off with 1000 primes and then if you need more explore up to 10,000, then 100,000. Sieve's are quick and you'll avoid division.

2) A hash set seems reasonable. Another viable approach (for small g_MaxTested) is a BitArray. This becomes less appealing as g_MaxTested gets larger because the primes become more spread out.

3) A simple approach is to make each public method `lock` a locker object. This means only one thread can interact with your class at once.

If you want me to write some code to explain my points let me know.

**Update**

How about initialising the class with all the primes less than 10^7 (664,579 according to wikipedia), then if you get a number:

- < 10^7 do a simple membership check
- between 10^7 and (10^7)^2 see if any of your primes divide into it
- > 10^14 check whether any of your primes divide into it, if not see if any of the odd numbers in the range 10^7 to sqrt(number) divide it.

It is probably best to store the primes as uint rather than ulong to save on memory.

Also 10^7 is arbitrary and you should change this to suit your space / time requirements.

Comment: actually, upperbound will be most of time below 10^7, but the class is part of an utility library so it have to works well for any ulong value. 1. I understand your point of view, but doesn't your approach requires to maintain an array of bool, with the length of all integers ? 2. don't see how to replace the hashset with a bitarray. Can you explain this point ? 3. I know the lock object. I was actually thinking about a more subtle (and complex) behavior. Having the possibility of a worker thread for exploration, and several "readers", locked only if requested number is below explored

Comment: I've added an approach that works well for numbers that aren't too large and will be threadsafe (without the need for locks)

Comment: Also, do you really need to work with ulongs? storing all the primes up to ulong.MaxValue will require a **lot** of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes about the tests:

1. The first the method has a smell: [Conditional Test Logic](http://xunitpatterns.com/Conditional%20Test%20Logic.html). I'd extract out the `do-while` loop to an `enumeratePrimesBelow(ulong upperLimit)` method. It would improve readability a lot.
2. ```
   Assert.IsFalse(Primes.IsPrime(1));
   ```

   I'd create a [custom assertion method](http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html) for that:

   ```
   public void AssertIsNotPrime(ulong value) {
       Assert.IsFalse(Primes.IsPrime(value));
   }
   ```

   It would make the tests easier to read.
3. `_1IsNotPrimeTest`, `_2IsPrimeTest`, `_3IsPrimeTest`, `_42IsNotPrimeTest` etc. should be a [parameterized test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html). I don't know whether C# unit testing frameworks supports it or not.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. You are right, I can make my code more readable. For your 3rd item, unfortunately MS OOB test framework does not provides parameterized test. This is not a big issue as I also use Pex which helps find and generate test cases.